# Solving an Elliptic Equation?

Tags: differential-equations

[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}];

```
NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[f[x,y],{x,y}] == (Exp[[(f[x, y]) + ( 
             Log[(x - 0.29)^2 + (y - 0.29)^2] + 
              Log[(x - 0.32)^2 + (y - 0.32)^2] )]] - 1)}, f, {x, 
       y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be an edit on your previous question, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187876/how-do-i-solve-the-following-elliptic-equation?

Comment: Yes Michael it is.

Comment: You have syntax problems. For example, see the tutorial on [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html). Look at the documentation for [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html)

Comment: There is an "edit" button under your other post that you can use to update that question with this code.

Comment: Okay thanks. Sorry about that guys.

Comment: I fixed the syntax and I still get errors. The problem seems to be the f[x,y] in the exponential on the right hand side of the equation. The error I get is that the right hand side "is not a polynomial".